# Cocoa Programming, setting the delegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm moving on from iOS to Cocoa and trying to muddle through my first few programs. I thought it would be simple to add an `NSComboBox` to my form, well that part was. I added `<NSComboBoxDelegate, NSComboBoxDataSource>` to my interface, two data callbacks, and the notifier:

```
@interface spcAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate,
                      NSComboBoxDelegate, NSComboBoxDataSource>

- (id)comboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox objectValueForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInComboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox;

- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification;

@end
```

I control dragged the combobox to the app delegate (which is the only class in my simple default app) and wired up the delegate and data source but none of those events fire.  I thought app delegate was correct but since it didn't fire, I also tried "file owner" and "application".   I didn't think those would work and they didn't.

Whats the right way to wire up the delegate/data source for an `NSComboBox` in a Cocoa app?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "it didn't fire," what are you doing to test that? Breakpoint in the debugger? NSLog?

Comment: By "didn't fire" I mean that I added the delegate methods and set a breakpoint in them that was not reached.  You are probably thinking that it makes sense that the two data methods were not reached but that comboBoxSelectionDidChange should have been reachable.  Again my fault as I had wired that event incorrectly.  So I actually had two propblems but the primary fix was realizing that there was a (new?) checkbox to indicate that I was using a data source.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Provided you've actually implemented those methods in your `spcAppDelegate.m` file, you may want to double-check that `Uses Data Source` is checked for the `NSComboBox` in the nib file in Interface Builder:

[image]

Note that it wasn't set by default in a quick test project I created. Running without that checkbox set should log the following to console when you launch the app:

```
NSComboBox[2236:403] *** -[NSComboBox setDataSource:] should not be called when
          usesDataSource is set to NO
NSComboBox[2236:403] *** -[NSComboBoxCell setDataSource:] should not be called 
             when usesDataSource is set to NO
```

While the [NSComboBox Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is somewhat helpful, when I was first learning, I found that if there were companion guides linked to for a class, those were much more helpful in understanding how one should use the class in practice. If you look at the top of the `NSComboBox` class reference at the **Companion Guide**, you'll see [Combo Box Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ComboBox/ComboBox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000020i).

To set up a combo box that uses a data source, you could use something like the following:

spcAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface spcAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate,
                  NSComboBoxDelegate, NSComboBoxDataSource> {
    IBOutlet NSWindow            *window;
    IBOutlet NSComboBox            *comboBox;
    NSMutableArray                *comboBoxItems;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

spcAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "spcAppDelegate.h"
@implementation spcAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        comboBoxItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:
               [@"Cocoa Programming setting the delegate"
                                        componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [comboBoxItems release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInComboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox {
    return [comboBoxItems count];
}
- (id)comboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox objectValueForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (aComboBox == comboBox) {
        return [comboBoxItems objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    return nil;
}
- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@] value == %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]),
      NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [comboBoxItems objectAtIndex:
        [(NSComboBox *)[notification object] indexOfSelectedItem]]);

}
@end
```

Sample Project: http://github.com/NSGod/NSComboBox.

Comment: Thanks very much.   It was "use data source".  I had done *almost* everything right :)

Comment: This is unbelievably frustrating that even in OS 10.11 & Xcode 8 it will NOT work if you do not check the box in the Xib -- even if you set `comboBox.usesDataSource = true` programmatically!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar situation yesterday until I remembered to hook up the File Owner data source to the IBOutlet in IB:

[image]